# ssh remote run - problems

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, ssh, terminal

This will print 4 lines:

```
ssh root@remote_ip "service iptables restart"
```

Output:

```
iptables: Flushing firewall rules: [  OK  ]
iptables: Setting chains to policy ACCEPT: filter [  OK  ]
iptables: Unloading modules: [  OK  ]
iptables: Applying firewall rules: [  OK  ]
```

Same command inside of **VAR=$()**

```
VAR=$(ssh root@remote_ip "service iptables restart")
echo $VAR
```

This time it prints only this line:

```
iptables: Applying firewall rules: [ OK ]: filter [ OK ]
```

That line is not even a line from the standard 4 line output.

makes no sense to me.

Also.. I want to see the 4 line output like the original.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the output from the command contains carriage-returns (CRLF or `\r\n`, as DOS does it), this will be the effect:

```
$ text=$( printf 'A\r\nB\r\nC\r\n' )
$ echo $text
 C
```

However, if you properly quote your variable when you echo it:

```
$ echo "$text"
A
B
C
```